# Why should I use Apple's CGLShareGroup for OpenCL and OpenGL interoperability

Tags: macos, opengl, opencl, gpgpu

As OpenCL has a built-in support in sharing data with OpenGL, I wonder if I should use Apple's CGLShareGroup to create my OpenCL context (as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/shareGroups/shareGroups.html)), or if I can create an OpenCL context and share data with OpenGL using the standard OpenCL API, without losing anything.

Note that I use the standard OpenCL API rather than Apple `gcl_*` API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the interop API are the same regardless of platform (e.g., clEnqueueAcquireOpenGL objects) the *way* to create an interop OpenCL context is OS-specific. On Apple you use CGLShareGroup. See section "9.7 Creating CL context from a GL context or share group" from the OpenCL 1.1 specification.

Comment: But it works even if I create the context without CGLShareGroup. So what's the ADVANTAGE of using CGLShareGroup?

Comment: Interesting. It seems outside of the spec and examples, so the advantage would be spec compliance and possibly future stability. Also, your current technique might not work with all CL/GL driver combinations (e.e., did you try AMD, NVIDIA, and Intel GPU machines?)

Comment: Actually, I do it via IOSurface: I start with an IOSurface, I create an OpenCL image from it using `clCreateImageFromIOSurface2DAPPLE`, and then create a GLTexture from the IOSurface using `CGLTexImageIOSurface2D`.
This is well documented. As far as I understand this is very efficient on 10.9, and does not involve memory coping under the hood. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't use IOSurface, just OpenGL / OpenCL interop, so I can't help. What you are doing sounds reasonable.